# problem in reading xml file from jar

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file not found exception in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755806/file-not-found-exception-in-jar)

hi
I have one class 
and in that i have one file
Document doc = db.parse(element.xml);
but when i create jar it is not getting loaded,
so please tell me is there any other way to give path for file,
so i can run my jar

Comment: have you tried with `com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class loader to load any resource from class path:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml");
    db.parse(input);
```

Comment: +1 for using Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

Answer (score 1):

```
db.parse(Foo.class.getResource("/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml").toString());
```

Where Foo is the class in which you are writing this code which is in the same jar

Comment: you are welcomed to mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Call [`getResourceAsStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and read the data from the stream:

```
db.parse(Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml"));
```

You should always prefer to use streams to read the data rather than expecting there to be a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

User ClassLoader.getSystemResource("root/src/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml").getPath(); to point to xml's or any resource files..

Note : You must add  xml file location to Classpath . (-Djava.class.path="C:\project\resources" ) where xml's are present at C:\project\resources

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader loadClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() ; 

InputStream in =  
new InputStreamReader(loadClass.getResourceAsStream("com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml") );
```